# How can I achieve alpha gradient effect in iOS

Tags: swift, core-graphics, metal, core-image

I want to achieve something similar to this alpha effect but in gradient. This effect should be applied to the UIImage. The alpha value on top should be 0 and goes towards 1 to the bottom of the image. Right now, I drew an image using the code but it changes the alpha of the whole image.

```
func imageWithAlpha(img: UIImage!, value: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, false, img.scale)
    img.draw(at: CGPoint.zero, blendMode: .normal, alpha: value)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

[image]